# Excel Partially lookup to different workbooks

Tags: excel

I've got two workbooks as follow:

workbook A:

```
Name    Code
Jay      J
Katy     K
```

workbook B:

```
Full Name    Age
Jay_Yeung     26
Katy_Yip      27
```

How to partially vlookup of values to achieve follow?

```
Full Name    Age   Code
Jay_Yeung     26    J
Katy_Yip      27    K
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the matching logic here?  For example, is it possible that the `Name` column of workbook A might have a last name instead?  E.g. wk A could have the last name `Yeung`?

Comment: If the full name in workbook B contains name that partially matches with the name in workbook A, then bring back the value of Code in workbook A to B.

Comment: @pnuts Could you explain little bit further?

Comment: This sort of problem would better be handled in a database rather than Excel.

Comment: What if your `Workbook A` also has a "Jay" that's really "Jay Smith", and not "Jay Yeung". How do you know which Jay to match with "Jay Yueng"? At first I would say just use the first name of Workbook B, and `Index/Match`.  ...but what if there are duplicates?